# allure pytest: no suites hierarchy in report

Tags: python, pytest, allure

i am running tests using pytest and allure-python. my test's are divided between modules and classes. however. when the report is generated, 'suites' tab contains only a single level - the actual functions.

instead what i would expected to see is:
[image: good allure]

my FS and pytest hierarchy:
[image: hierarchy]

i'm running:

```
pytest -s -v --aluredir='xx' -m 'tags' tests/
```